# Why do I get an unmappable character for encoding UTF-8 when I changed maven java compiler plugin from 1.5 to 1.6?

Tags: java, compiler-construction, encoding, maven

I have a Java project and I'm using Apache Maven. All this time I was using Maven Java compiler plugin with parameters *source=1.5* and *target=1.5* defined in pom.xml file. Since I changed it to *source=1.6* and *target=1.6* I'm getting the following error:

> XXXXXXXX.java:[54,27] unmappable character for encoding UTF-8

I've been testing different configurations and I turned *showWarnings* to value *true* so I could see that with value *1.5* for *source* and *target* this is a warning and not an error.

I need to change the Java compiler configuration anyway. Does anybody know why is this so and how can I solve this problem without editing all Java source files (there are hundreds of files with this issue now)?

Comment: Have you looked at what is at line 54 column 27 of file XXXXXXXX.java to see what is there? Try it with a hex capable editor as well, or something that can show hidden characters like notepad++

Comment: It's an encoding problem with an special latin character in a paragraph (all errors are in code comments). If I try with _encoding=ISO-8859-1_ it compiles OK (I cannot change the whole project character encoding anyhow). My question is: why is this an error with _source=1.6_ and _target=1.6_ and it's a warning with _source=1.5_ and _target=1.5_?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> My question is: why is this an error with source=1.6 and target=1.6
>   and it's a warning with source=1.5 and target=1.5?

Short anwser, because [they said so](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html):

> -source 1.6 This is the default value. No language changes were
>   introduced in Java SE 6. However, encoding errors in source files are
>   **now reported as errors, instead of warnings, as previously**.

@DaveG concerns are valid, and you should try to:

- Change the file encoding of your source files
- find/replace those chars with your IDE

Comment: Good catch. Java has historically been really lax about encoding errors. I have been trying to get folks to use it in a way that reports encoding errors as errors, but you have to work at it.  It's good that these are now caught.

Comment: Absolutely. This will save hours of tedious debugging and "my webapp shows weird chars" questions on SO!

Comment: @Brian awesome catch on that.  Hadn't considered chasing it down through the documentation

Comment: Why this throw error even in comments? It realy not so funny.